# LaTeX Referenz in English

Tags: discussion, community

Not too long ago, I think it was at the beginning of November, the [LaTeX Referenz](http://www.lehmanns.de/page/latexreferenz) by Herbert Voß was released for free, but its in German (am not saying its a bad thing). Are there any plans on translating this into English or can anyone do it? It is a very good quick reference and would love to see an English translation. If any one knows where I can get one I would appreciate it. May be Herbert Voß could answer this :-).

Comment: Yes, There is an english version also: [LaTeX Quick Reference, by Herbert Voß (UIT Cambridge, 2011. vi+234 pp. Paperback, US$29.95. ISBN 9781906860219)](http://www.uit.co.uk/BK-LREF/HomePage) and it's review as usual at [TUG Book Reviews](http://tug.org/books/reviews/tb107reviews-vossltxref.html). Recently Herbert himself gave a [Link to his books/contents](http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/Books/) but `LaTeX reference` book does not have english version of table of contents. So you might need to contact him via email on above website for more info.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on the main site? :)

Comment: I'm going to reopen the original version of this  question and close this one: it's not meta as it's not about TeX-sx itself.

Comment: @texenthusiast That's not the same book: the free one in German is more of a pamphlet (32 pages), while the English one you link to is 160 pages long. I think it's a translation of http://www.amazon.de/LaTeX-Referenz-Herbert-Vo%C3%9F/dp/3865413668/ref=sr_1_10?ie=UTF8&qid=1386529679&sr=8-10&keywords=Herbert+Voss.

Comment: **Cross-posted: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147459/latex-referenz-in-english**